# Looking to source alignment studs for circuit board

Tags: connector

I am building a completely custom tube amp with two amp boards (L & R) that slide in and out of a wooden case I've made.

I am having trouble sourcing a specific component.

I'm not really sure what they are called, but it's an alignment stud used to align and ground the board prior to inserting the board all the way in the chassis.

Iv'e attached a picture of a Dell Poweredge M610 Motherboard with the studs in question circled in red.

[image]

Anyone have an idea on where something similar could be sourced? Thank you ahead of time.

Comment: For a one-off homebuild, find a junk computer with the parts you require, and extract them.

Comment: Try searching for self-clinching pilot pins or some variant of that. Failing that, grab a lathe and make them.

Comment: @Ecnerwal I considered that but they only appear on high end blade systems making them hard to come by.

Comment: @Spehro Pefhany I'll take your suggestion and make them. It should only require turning a rod on a lathe and thread it into a block that will be screwed to the mainboard. Then maybe another block with a chamfered hole to guide it.

Answer (score 3):

This can usually be found as part of modular backplane connectors.

For example, here are some parts from the TE connectivity (tyco) [catalog](http://www.te.com/usa-en/plp/backplane-guide-hardware/Y30J7.html):

- 5223985-x: guide pin (diam. 4.85mm)
- 5223986-x: receptacle

Molex also has similar things:

- 76153-1001: guide pin (diam. 5.5mm)
- 75234-1478: receptacle

And probably many others manufacturers have some. To find them, go in mouser/digikey search engines, and try search words like *backplane* and *guide*.